# Mongo 3.0.14 getting this error every few weeks or so and slowing down primary

Tags: mongodb

**Mongo Cluster 3.0.14**

SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server

**query local.oplog.rs query:**

`{ ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1543286846000|2 } } planSummary: COLLSCAN cursorid:22301727629 ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:42402092 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:337900 nreturned:2 reslen:1737 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 675802 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 337901 } }, oplog: { acquireCount: { r: 337901 } } }`

6196840ms

Once this finishes, all mongo operations go back to being fast again.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the query you run is doing a collection scan on the entire collection, it means it iterates over all the items.
Try to add an index on ghe fiels named: ts. 
I think it will. Improve performance, and migbt solve your problem.

Comment: oplog is an internal table to mongo that keeps track of operations.....so this is not some query over a collection that our application is using

Comment: That is really my question....why is this internal mongo process taking so long and slowing down other operations

Comment: oh, i see now, didn't notice its an oplog operation, in that case i don't know :/